# AWS ELB leaks private ip address via dns name that are only accessible via VPN - can this be considered a security risk?

Tags: domain-name-system, amazon-web-services, security

I'm using VPN for my AWS development environment and i have some databases running on EC2 behind an ELB. The thing is whenever i connect to them via VPN i will use database-12345678.elb.us-east-1.amazonaws.com and my ELB will forward it accordingly. However i just found out that if i resolve this FQDN within public internet (google dns for example) it will also return the private IP Address. It seems like even when connected to VPN the DNS queries happen over public DNS.I never experienced this kind of configuration usually the VPN Client will get a reference to dns service running inside the VPN upon configuration.
I just was curious if this would be considered a security threat within a corporate network? It just doesn't feel right on the other hand enumeration is basically impossible because all the elb FQDN's contain the random generated number so it's basically impossible to guess. Can somebody provide guidance? Thanks

Comment: That might be more topical on the security SE site but imho private IP’s are not particularly sensitive information and about as sensitive as disclosing that your office building has multiple floors and the IT office is located behind a blue door labeled with “IT Office”

Comment: Generally you wouldn't give out internal IPs, but in this case I suspect there is no significant security issue.